# Amazon MWS PHP5.3 Error: Timestamp Must Follow ISO8601

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

My Amazon MWS integration was working perfectly till yesterday. But today I received this error when using ListOrders: **Timestamp Must Follow ISO8601**

I suspect the culprit code to be:

$request->setCreatedAfter(new DateTime('2017-09-01 12:00:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC')));

Please help me fix the error.

Comment: I am seeing the same problem since yesterday afternoon, no amount of tweaking my ISO8601 timestamp formats has made any difference.

Comment: I have the same problem since yesterday :(

Comment: It's working again now...

Comment: i have the same problem now..somethimes it happens...

Answer (score 2):

If you've seen it working and you've not made any changes it will still be producing the correct timestamp.

We have an integration with Amazon that's been working happily for years and is experiencing this error today. We think it's an issue on Amazon's side and are raising a support request with them to confirm.

**Update:**
We're now seeing requests succeed again so Amazon appear to have resolved the issue. I'd suggest trying your request again as it should now work.

Comment: There's a [thread on the MWS forum](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/error-started-suddenly-code-untouched-for-a-year-malformedinput-timestamp-must-follow-iso8601/390203/4) from someone else having the same issue.

Comment: We're having the same issue since 2018-06-03 18:00. It started to get better since 2018-03-07 10:41, but we still get that "Malformed input" error quite often. Also, we're calling other actions like "SubmitFeed" and "ListOrderItems" with the same timestamp format but without getting that error.